# Is the tag "Veronica-Mars" or "Veronica-Mars-The-Movie"?

Tags: discussion, tags

TV show and film have the same name.  Don't know if I need to suffix with "-the-movie" or not.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know there already was a meta question on it when editing your post. I still think, though the `the` is superflous and damaging and will answer/comment accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I would presume that since the TV show came first, that you would use

[veronica-mars](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veronica-mars) for the TV show

and

[veronica-mars-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veronica-mars-movie) for the movie

Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: You guys are the ones with the experience on this SE sub-division; figured I'd ask.

Comment: @JoshDM Its not *that* common to have TV / Movie show name clashes.  We have sherlock (the UK TV show), sherlock-holmes (the Robert Downey Junior movie) for example.  But if the name would be identical, I would go for "the movie".

Comment: To be honest, it's probably a situation where using both is helpful. To give a related example that isn't as obvious, if you asked a question about the movie "Serenity", it would be useful to tag it "Firefly" after the original TV show as well, as people searching for one tag are likely to be knowledgeable/interested in the other.

Comment: Almost, but 9 letters of precious tag space is complete overkill for just a meta appendage, see my answer.

Comment: @AndrewMartin Yet we're not tagging by *related* topics, but by the topics of the actual question. A question that really only is about *Serenity* without any connection to *Firefly* just doesn't deserve that tag. People interested in `firefly` should be knowledgable enough to check for `serenity` anyway.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: I suppose. If I created a new question on it, it would be my instinct to automatically tag the series too, just to draw more attention, but I get what you're saying.

Comment: Could you maybe add some explanations of why you prefer `-the-movie` over `-movie`, since the OP hasn't given one yet and your answer seems a bit ad hoc?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson. Gosh, because I didn't know anything about Veronica Mars and I thought given the specific choice of the OP suggesting the `-the-movie` it had been used as the title as some movies do.  I'm happy with `-movie` too, and will update the answer.

Comment: @iandotkelly In fact that was also my intuition (given that I also have absolutely no knowledge about this movie, let alone the TV-show), which might speak for the misleadability of the tag.

Answer (score 1):

While I am more or less in favour of *iandotkelly*'s approach, the tag [veronica-mars-the-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veronica-mars-the-movie) is overly complicated and verbose and sounds like an actual title instead of a title with a meta appendage (and in fact when seeing the tag I thought the movie was titled *Veronica Mars - The Movie*, only to see that it wasn't). Especially when seeing other future movie-TV-overlaps, such policy only leads to cluttering the very (very<sup>1</sup>) short 25-character tag space with unneccessary information.

**I would thus suggest to use the much more concise [veronica-mars-movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veronica-mars-movie)**, especially in consideration of establishing a policy and precedent for future (possibly longer) movie-TV-overlap titles.

---

I also want to appologize for changing the tag as described above, since I didn't know there already was a meta discussion on it. Feel free to revert my changes if the community decides for a different solution.

---

<sup>1</sup> very very very!

Comment: Just looking, both of these options exist already (probably created today, I'd bet). I agree, without the "the" is probably a better option.

Comment: I will leave the original as is for a while till meta comes to a consensus.  @Paulster2 - note the author of this question and the author of the question that uses the tag.

Comment: @JoshDM Could you provide an explanation (be it as an individual answer, an appendage to your question or a comment to *iandotkelly*'s or my answer) of why you prefer `-the-movie` over `-movie`? I'd be interested in the reasons driving this decision.

Answer (score -1):

If we ignore for a second that one is a tv show and the other is a movie, the established solution is obvious:

[veronica-mars](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veronica-mars) and [veronica-mars-2014](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veronica-mars-2014)

Two works of art with the same title are usually distinguished by adding the year to the newer one. This is common both for movies ([total-recall](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/total-recall) vs. [total-recall-2012](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/total-recall-2012)) as well as tv shows (e.g. the old and new *Battlestar Galactica*).

I think it would be logical to apply this to clashes between tv shows and movies as well.

To avoid any confusion we could even do

[veronica-mars-2004](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veronica-mars-2004) and [veronica-mars-2014](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veronica-mars-2014)

Comment: Your examples are movies and their disassociated movie remakes or tv series and their disassociated tv series remakes. This is a canon extension of the tv series that happens to be a feature film.

Comment: @JoshDM True, my examples are all remakes. However, the year naming convention is also common for unrelated works like "Castle (2003)" (an unknown mini-series) and "Castle (2009)" (the well known tv show). My point was that this is the usual way to handle name clashes, and the Veronica Mars case is just a special version of this imo.

Comment: The advantage of this notation is that it is short and unambiguous for almost all cases. Also, it is future-proof. Just imagine if they make a remake of the _Veronica Mars_ movie in 2020. Suddenly you have 3 things to tag [tag:Veronica Mars], two of which are movies. Do you tag the movies [tag:veronica-mars-movie] and [tag:veronica-mars-movie-2020] then? I hope you see where this is going.

Comment: And yes, I am aware that a Veronica Mars movie remake is unlikely. But we see more and more movies being made into series (e.g. Sleepy Hollow, Hannibal) and vice versa. And with the tendency of Hollywood to make remakes, that's not an unimaginable scenario. I think the year notation solves current and future naming problems.

Comment: @JoshDM While I am also not so much in favour of *atticae*'s solution (be it either because TV-shows usually don't have an exact release moment, neccessitating a consens about what year to use, or because I'd like the differentiation between movies and TV-shows to be more prominent), I still don't think that your argument of disassociated remakes vs canon extensions holds particularly strong.

Comment: While I would still prefer `-tv` and `-movie` (for the reasons given in my above comment), you certainly got a point regarding unification, conciseness and forward-compatibility.